# Does any Hyper-geometric function can be analytically continuated to the whole complex plain except $e^{\pm i\pi/3}$

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

We all know that the famous Hypergeoemtric function $_2F_1$ has an integral form as follows:

$$_2F_1(a,b,c;z)=-\frac{e^{-i\pi c} \Gamma(c)}{4\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c-b)\sin\pi b\sin\pi(c-b)}\int_P t^{b-1}(1-t)^{c-b-}(1-zt)^{-a}dt,$$

where $c\neq0,-1,-2,...$ and $P$ is Pochhammer contour. This integral form can give an analytic continuation of Hypergeometric function from $|z|<1$ to the whole $z$-plain except the slit $[1,\infty]$.

Recently, I read a paper -

- W. Becken, P. Schmelcher, *The analytic continuation of the Gaussian hypergeometric function $_2F_1(a,b,c;z)$ for arbitrary parameters*, Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics **126** (2000) 449–478. https://doi.org/10.1016/S0377-0427(00)00267-3, https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82108003.pdf

The paper gave us a conclusion that Gaussian hypergeometric function can be analytically continuated to the whole complex $z$-plain excluding only $e^{\pm i\pi/3}$. If the conclusion is true, it will help me a lot since the continuation domain covers nearly a whole plain, and I can regard the hypergeometric function as an entire function except two exact points. Can I directly use this conclusion? Is this conclusion verified formally in maths world? Is the continuated function single-valued?

Comment: You seem to be asking whether a published paper is correct.  If so, then this sort of general question is not suitable for MO.  If you have a specific question about a particular part of the proof, then that might be more appropriate.

Comment: "[Verified formally](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant)" doesn't quite mean what you think it means. Do you just mean "proved"?

Comment: Hypergeometric function has an analytic continuation along any path in the plane which does not pass through $0$ and $1$.

Comment: I think a better question to ask is what can the authors mean by their statement about different analytic continuations in different transforms of $z$ being enough for all the plane except two points via "Kummer-type solutions which are power series in the arguments $z$, $z/(z-1)$, $(1/z)$, $1-(1/z)$, $1/z$, $1/(1-z)$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuation to the whole $z$-plane?  As stated, not true.  Example:
$$
{}_2F_1\left(-\frac12,1;1;z\right) = (1-z)^{1/2},\quad |z|<1,
$$
cannot be extended analytically to any neighborhood of $z=1$.

Comment: The OP is willing to exclude points, it seems, but is rather specific about which ones

Comment: On looking at the paper, it's not clear that the OP has correctly conveyed the result, or rather, the question doesn't reflect the claim in the paper, which is not clear to me.